# How do i display a single word as a hyper link from complete message in angular

Tags: angular

I am displaying a message on my angular app using interpolation. The message include name of a person too. I am using @ to specify the person name. what i want is where ever any persons name come in message which i am displaying it should be a hyper link. when click to the link person gets redirected to the person profile.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

<del>You want to build a pipe directive</del>
It turns out that manipulating DOM elements is much better suited for directives and components.

Here is my working [StackBlitz directive](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-example-directive?embed=1&file=src/app/username.directive.ts).

**Regular Expression Method**

I got help to find the regex `/@[0-9a-zA-Z]{5,20}(?=\\s|$)/` that works:

```
// REGEX-MATCH AND REPLACE THE USERNAME SUBSTRING(S)
ngAfterViewInit(){
    this.initialText = this.el.nativeElement.innerText;

    this.finalText = this.initialText.replace(/@[0-9a-zA-Z]{5,20}(?=\\s|$)/, function(username) {
        return `<a href="#${username.substring(1)}">${username}</a>`;
    });
```

**Looping Method**

When looping you must test every word to check for multiple occurrences of `@xxxxxxx` usernames.

- Get any group of text
- split each word at every space
- check each word for @xx match
- word for @username text references
- wrap @username instances in an  tag
- replace the element's original text with finalText
- this does not check for special characters
- this does not check for already wrapped @usernames

Both versions are in the StackBlitz with working `innerHTML` replacement.

```
ngAfterViewInit(){
    this.initialText = this.el.nativeElement.innerText;
    if (this.initialText && this.initialText.length > 0) {
        for (let text of this.initialText.split(" ")) {
            if (text.startsWith("@") && text.length > 1){
              this.finalText += `<a href="#${text.substring(1)}">${text}</a> `;
            } else {
              this.finalText += text + " ";
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: ya sure i will share result as soon as i complete the work. But my main issue is regular expression i am not getting the correct one @Ben Racicot